# How to fix this error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder?

Tags: java, maven, mule

When running my maven plugin executing its goal "install" I get the the error that tells me that the "staticloggerbinder" has not been found.

I have gone through every post here in stackoverflow in which they were talking about this error ( very very common apparently ).  What they suggest in their majority is to put as a dependency what follows:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I will paste here the `mvn dependency:tree`  just so you see how my classpath:

```
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.13:compile
[INFO] +- com.mulesoft.muleesb:mule-core-ee:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.mule:mule-core:jar:3.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mule.extensions:mule-extensions-api:jar:1.0.0-alpha-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.stephenc.eaio-uuid:uuid:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.github.stephenc.eaio-grabbag:grabbag:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.lmax:disruptor:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jcl:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- asm:asm-commons:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- asm:asm-tree:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mule.mvel:mule-mvel2:jar:2.1.9-MULE-008:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jgrapht:jgrapht-jdk1.5:jar:0.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.mulesoft.licm:licm:jar:1.1.5:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- de.schlichtherle:truelicense:jar:1.29:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- de.schlichtherle:truexml:jar:1.29:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- opensymphony:propertyset:jar:1.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- opensymphony:oscore:jar:2.2.4:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.7.3:provided
[INFO] +- com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-spring-config-ee:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-multi-tx-ee:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-xa-tx-ee:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-cache-ee:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-file:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-http:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-ssl:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-tcp:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:coyote:jar:6.0.44:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:juli:jar:6.0.44:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.samba.jcifs:jcifs:jar:1.3.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mule.modules:mule-module-http:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-framework:jar:2.3.21:provided
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http-server:jar:2.3.21:provided
[INFO] |     |  \- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http:jar:2.3.21:provided
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.grizzly:connection-pool:jar:2.3.21:provided
[INFO] |     +- com.ning:async-http-client:jar:1.9.31:provided
[INFO] |     \- org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-websockets:jar:2.3.21:provided
[INFO] +- com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports:mule-transport-jdbc-ee:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-jdbc:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.flatpack:flatpack:jar:3.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1.3:provided
[INFO] |  \- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:provided
[INFO] +- com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports:mule-transport-jms-ee:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-jms:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:provided
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |        +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |        \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-vm:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-scripting:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-builders:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:indy:2.4.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.python:jython-standalone:jar:2.7.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.script:js-engine:jar:jdk14:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.mozilla:rhino:jar:1.7R4:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jruby:jruby-core:jar:1.7.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jruby:jruby-stdlib:jar:1.7.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jruby.joni:joni:jar:2.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jnr-netdb:jar:1.1.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jnr-enxio:jar:0.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jnr-unixsocket:jar:0.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jnr-posix:jar:2.5.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jruby.extras:bytelist:jar:1.0.10:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jnr-constants:jar:0.8.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jruby.jcodings:jcodings:jar:1.0.10:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:1.2.5:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.11:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- jline:jline:jar:2.7:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.jcraft:jzlib:jar:1.1.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.headius:invokebinder:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.jnr:jnr-ffi:jar:1.0.4:provided
[INFO] |  |     +- com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:native:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT:provided (version selected from constraint [1.2.1,1.3.0))
[INFO] |  |     \- com.github.jnr:jnr-x86asm:jar:1.0.2:provided (version selected from constraint [1.0.2,))
[INFO] |  \- javax.script:jruby-engine:jar:jdk14:1.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-xml:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.7:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.3.4.O:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.stax-utils:stax-utils:jar:20080702:provided
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:jar:9.6.0-1:provided
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:jar:xqj:9.6.0-1:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.xml.xquery:xqj-api:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.mule.tests:mule-tests-functional:jar:3.7.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-extensions-support:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mule.extensions:mule-extensions-annotations:jar:1.0.0-alpha-1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ftpserver:ftpserver-core:jar:1.0.6:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.mina:mina-core:jar:2.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ftpserver:ftplet-api:jar:1.0.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.sshd:sshd-core:jar:0.6.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.50:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-dbutils:commons-dbutils:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mule:mule-core:test-jar:tests:3.7.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] |     \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] +- com.sybase.jdbc4.utils:jconn4:jar:7.07_SP133_Build_27244:compile
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-sfdc:jar:7.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.force.api:force-wsc:jar:36.2.0-hf1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.force.api:force-metadata-api:jar:36.0.0-hf1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.force.api:force-partner-api:jar:36.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.cometd.java:cometd-java-client:jar:3.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.cometd.java:bayeux-api:jar:3.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.cometd.java:cometd-java-common:jar:3.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util-ajax:jar:9.2.14.v20151106:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.14.v20151106:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.14.v20151106:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.2.14.v20151106:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.2.14.v20151106:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.intellij:annotations:jar:12.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- ca.juliusdavies:not-yet-commons-ssl:jar:0.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.5.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.mule.wsdlinvoker:dynamic-wsdl-invoker:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.antlr:antlr4:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mule.tools.devkit:mule-devkit-shade:jar:3.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-db:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.5:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.9:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.experlog:xapool:jar:1.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.mule.common:mule-common:jar:3.7.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.json:json:jar:20140107:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-batch-ee:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-kryo-serializer-ee:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |     +- com.esotericsoftware:kryo-shaded:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO] |     |  \- com.esotericsoftware:minlog:jar:1.3.0:provided
[INFO] |     \- de.javakaffee:kryo-serializers:jar:0.29:provided
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-spring-config:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.mule.modules:mule-module-annotations:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |     \- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2:provided
[INFO] +- com.mulesoft.weave:mule-plugin-weave_2.11:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.5:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.mulesoft.weave:core_2.11:jar:1.0.3:provided
[INFO] |     +- org.spire-math:spire_2.11:jar:0.9.0:provided
[INFO] |     |  +- org.spire-math:spire-macros_2.11:jar:0.9.0:provided
[INFO] |     |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.11.4:provided
[INFO] |     |  \- org.typelevel:machinist_2.11:jar:0.3.0:provided
[INFO] |     +- org.parboiled:parboiled_2.11:jar:2.1.0:provided
[INFO] |     |  \- com.chuusai:shapeless_2.11:jar:2.1.0:provided
[INFO] |     +- io.spray:spray-json_2.11:jar:1.3.1:provided
[INFO] |     +- org.threeten:threetenbp:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.0.1:provided
[INFO] \- org.mule.modules:mule-module-json:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO]    +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-validation:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO]    |  +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.4.0:provided
[INFO]    |  |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:provided
[INFO]    |  \- org.mule.modules:mule-module-extensions-spring-support:jar:3.7.3:provided
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.11:provided
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.11:provided
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.11:provided
[INFO]    +- de.odysseus.staxon:staxon:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:provided
[INFO]    +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.3:provided
[INFO]    +- com.github.fge:json-schema-validator:jar:2.2.5:provided
[INFO]    |  +- com.github.fge:json-schema-core:jar:1.2.4:provided
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.github.fge:uri-template:jar:0.9:provided
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- com.github.fge:msg-simple:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO]    |  |  |     \- com.github.fge:btf:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO]    |  |  \- com.github.fge:jackson-coreutils:jar:1.8:provided
[INFO]    |  +- com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:jar:6.0:provided
[INFO]    |  +- javax.mail:mailapi:jar:1.4.3:provided
[INFO]    |  \- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:4.6:provided
[INFO]    \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.3:compile
[INFO]       \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.4.0:compile
```

I don´t know if you guys will require of my pom.xml, but if so please don´t hesitate to ask me for it.

Cheers

Edit:

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <name>...</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <mule.version>3.7.3</mule.version>
        <mule.tools.version>1.2</mule.tools.version>

        <muleApiUrl>...</muleApiUrl>
        <username>...</username>
        <password>....</password>
        <serverGroup>Development</serverGroup>  
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>

<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.nicholasastuart</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-mmc-rest-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>mule-deploy</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <muleApiUrl>${muleApiUrl}</muleApiUrl>
                <name>${artifactId}</name>
                <username>${username}</username>
                <password>${password}</password>
                <appDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/app</appDirectory>
                <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
                <version>${version}</version>
                <serverGroup>${serverGroup}</serverGroup>                           

            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                <inclusions>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                    </inclusions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>mappings/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/api/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Mule Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>


<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.21</version> <!-- Or a property: ${sl4j-api.version} -->
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>




        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Transports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jms-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.weave</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-plugin-weave_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-ws</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-json</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
          <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-release</id>
            <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

I am trying to use a maven plugin that allow me to deploy the artifacts that generate in my mule projects.  So, I include that plugin in my projects and the artifact should be deploy into my mule management console.

[Maven Mule Rest Plugin](https://github.com/NicholasAStuart/Maven-Mule-REST-Plugin)

1. download the repository to my local machine
2. 'mvn clean package'
3. I install the artifact on my .m2 maven repository
4. I include the plugin in the project from which I will send the artifact to deploy
5. 'mvn clean package' in that project + 'mvn mule-mmc-rest:deploy'
6. Getting that fancy error I am trying to get rid of by asking in here :)

Edit2:

**Building output - Project from which I want to deploy the artifact on my MMC**

```
$ mvn mule-mmc-rest:deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building yeah 6.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> mule-mmc-rest-plugin:1.2.2:deploy (default-cli) > compile @ dos >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- mule-app-maven-plugin:1.2:attach-test-resources (default-attach-test-resources) @ dos ---
[INFO] attaching test resource C:\a\git\api-flytetyme-pricing\src\main\app
[INFO]
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:add-resource (add-resource) @ dos ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ dos ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 11 resources
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\a\git\api-flytetyme-pricing\mappings
[INFO] Copying 22 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- mule-app-maven-plugin:1.2:filter-resources (default-filter-resources) @ dos ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:compile (default-compile) @ dos ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< mule-mmc-rest-plugin:1.2.2:deploy (default-cli) < compile @ dos <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- mule-mmc-rest-plugin:1.2.2:deploy (default-cli) @ dos ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.420 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-13T10:05:32+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/437M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.nicholasastuart:mule-mmc-rest-plugin:1.2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project dos: Execution default-cli of goal com.github.nicholasastuart:mule-mmc-rest-plugin:1.2.2:deploy failed: A required class was missing while executing com.github.nicholasastuart:mule-mmc-rest-plugin:1.2.2:deploy: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.github.nicholasastuart:mule-mmc-rest-plugin:1.2.2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/sebastian.xxxxx/.m2/repository/com/github/nicholasastuart/mule-mmc-rest-plugin/1.2.2/mule-mmc-rest-plugin-1.2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/sebastian.xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>uno:dos:6.0.0, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

EDIT3:

Ok, seeing that in the plugin dependencies the only slf4j that works is:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.slf4j-maven-plugin-log</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-maven-plugin-log</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have opted for including this, and only this dependency in the pom of the project in which I want to make use of this plugin to deploy the artifact and the result is the following:

**org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException**

now the error is different :)

I will see how to fix this ...

Comment: Hi Pierre, Thanks for this:

Tried that but does not work.  I will Edit3 my post and I will paste the dependency tree from both (plugin and project) again.... just so you see.

Comment: in my dependency tree from the plugin I can see that the version of slf4j-api is 1.6.1.  So I will put the same version on my project.

[INFO] +- com.googlecode.slf4j-maven-plugin-log:slf4j-maven-plugin-log:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile

Comment: It seems your problem is solved, that's great! Can you post the solution yourself and mark it as accepted? That may help people in the future having the same issue

Comment: Hi Pierre,
My problem wasn´t solved at that point as the plugin was missing more dependencies which I put following the same pattern as you posted.  Tomorrow at work I will post the whole solution for whoever is facing the same issue with this plugin.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of ups and downs with this plugin I found the way of making it work. So we just have to call the plugin on our project by pasting the following script:

```
    <plugin>
       <groupId>xxxxxxxx/groupId>
   <artifactId>xxxxxxxx</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.googlecode.slf4j-maven-plugin-log</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-maven-plugin-log</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>     
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
         <version>1.9.13</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
         <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
         <version>2.7.7</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>mule-deploy</id>
         <phase>install</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>deploy</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <muleApiUrl>${muleApiUrl}</muleApiUrl>
            <username>${username}</username>
            <password>${password}</password>
            <appDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/app</appDirectory>
            <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
            <version>${version}</version>
            <name>${name}</name>
            <deploymentName>${deploymentName}</deploymentName>
            <serverGroup>${serverGroup}</serverGroup>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Given the new elements, try the following:

Use the same version for both slf4j-api and slf4j-log4j12 (currently you 1.7.21 and 1.5.0 => use the most recent version for both, currently 1.7.21).

Your plugin does not specify the slf4j dependency in its pom.xml. Maybe the dependency is not properly pulled for this plugin. Try:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.nicholasastuart</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-mmc-rest-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ...
   ...
</plugin>
```

Original answer:

You are using SL4J, you may be missing the SL4J API dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.21</version> <!-- Or a property: ${sl4j-api.version} -->
</dependency>
```

If your project depends on SL4J, you'll need too dependencies:

- SL4J API
- A SL4J binding, such as the one you already use

Comment: still the same.  I have tried including all sl4j dependencies and still throwing that error. :(

Comment: Check my comment on your question, your pom.xml and maven build log will be helpful to help you.

Comment: Hi Pierre B,  please see the comments I have put on my post.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The dependency is right.I think you should clean your project and build again.

Comment: Hi Romeo,
I have done it more than twice. `mvn clean package`  but still giving me that error.

Comment: I also encountered similar problems before when using eclipse.I means use elicpe to clean and build not mvn.At first please try "Project-Clean-Clean projects selectd below".At second try "Project-Build Project/All" or just wait if you choose "Build Automatically".

Comment: I can only share these with you.If you still have problems,I'm sorry that I can't help you solve them.

Comment: Don't worry Romeo. More than appreciate your help.

Comment: My fault. Sorry.   I am building my projects with anypoint studio, but reaching to this point I just open a terminal and use maven commands to build clean and package.  So this does not provide me of an answer.